# C# socket net directed broadcast

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp, wireshark

I have several LANs(10.0.0.x) connected to a WAN(192.168.1.x).  Each through a router that allows a network directed broadcast.  This is to allow the devices in the LANs to be discovered by devices on the WAN.

I can send a broadcast on the LAN(10.0.0.255) and receive it on my socket.  But when I move to the WAN I can see it in wireshark, but not my socket.  I other words I have a device with address 10.0.0.1 sending the same message to 192.168.1.255 through a gateway but my socket is not receiving it.  When this happens the source address is the address of the router.  Here is the code for my socket:

```
                    udpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

                    //Assign the any IP of the machine and listen on port number 5000
                    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);

                    //Bind this address to the server
                    udpSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);

                    IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
                    //The epSender identifies the incoming clients
                    EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;

                    //Start receiving data
                    udpSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length,
                        SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveAnnounce), epSender);
```

I have a wireshark trace for each message but I'm not sure the best way to post it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand that UDP provides no guarantee that a packet will be received? (TCP uses a client to server connection) and that packets are broadcast to a 'multicast group' (this resembles an IP-address but must be in the range `224.0.0.0` to `239.255.255.255`) rather than to an IP.

Your use of `IPAddress.Any` tells it to use all network interfaces, but you never tell it which multicast group to use, I've never done this in C# myself, however it appears you want to add this line of code before your BeginReceiveFrom;

```
udpSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,SocketOptionName.AddMembership,new MulticastOption(TARGET_IP));
```

You should replace `TARGET_IP` with the address of your multicast group you wish to listen on.

I took that line of code from this site; http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=409

Comment: I understand what the UDP does, but I do want a broadcast, not multicast.  This is being used to discover controllers on a LAN behind and router.  That is why I need a broadcast to the WAN.  I'm not sending much data like this, just an announcement message.

Comment: That doesn't change the point that you aren't attaching to a multicast group, this is a necessary part of UDP (otherwise your packet would be accompanied with every other UDP packet going through your network card). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast

Comment: I guess I'm confused.  The socket I've created is receiving the message if it comes from the same LAN.  In both situations I'm sending the message to the broadcast address and haven't setup a multicast group.  I believe the port keeps it from receiving all the UDP packets but I guess the potential is there to receive all UDP data on the port.

Comment: If you can see the packet with wireshark, but can't receive it with your application, the only explanation I can see would be misconfigured multicast groups.
I've just found this while looking into it "A special definition exists for the IP broadcast address 255.255.255.255. It is the broadcast address of the zero network or 0.0.0.0, which in Internet Protocol standards stands for this network, i.e. the local network. Transmission to this address is limited by definition, in that it is never forwarded by the routers connecting the local network to other networks." your IPADDRESS.ALL is 0.0.0.0